# Which of the extension classes is this object?

Tags: java, object, types

Assuming I have an array of `User` objects where each object is actually one of two classes that extends `User`. `ComputerUser` and `HumanUser` both extend `User`.

Assume I'm iterating through the list and each object is named `o` when I am using it.

Can I figure out if `o` is a `ComputerUser` or `HumanUser` simply by comparing like this:

```
if(o.getClass().equals(ComputerUser.class)) {}
else if(o.getClass().equals(HumanUser.class)) {}
```

Comment: Isn't it easier just to test it youself?

Comment: Other bugs in code before I can check, I thought maybe someone would know off the top of their head.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if (o instanceof ComputerUser)
```

etc

Comment: Even though it's saved in an array of `User`s? It won't think it's a `User`?

Comment: instanceof check the dynamic type of the object, not the static type of the variable referencing it.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the instanceof operator :

```
if (o instanceof ComputerUser) { 
    ...
}
```

though this is considered poor use of object oriented programming.  An alternative is to leverage polymorphism and define the behavior appropriate to a ComputerUser vs a HumanUser as such :

```
abstract class User {

   abstract public void work();

}

class ComputerUser extends User { 

    @Override
    public void work() { 
       ...
       //specific to ComputerUser
    }

}

class HumanUser extends User { 

    @Override
    public void work() { 
       ...
       //specific to HumanUser
    }

}
```